# average of specific rows in a file

Tags: awk

I have 6 rows in files. I need to find average only of specific rows in a file and the others should be left as they are. The average should be calculated for A1 and A2, B1 and B2, other lines should stay as they are

Input:

```
A1  1   1   2
A2  5   6   1   
A3  1   1   1   
B1  10  12  12
B2  10  12  10
B3  100 200 300
```

Output:

```
A1A2  3    3.5   1.5     
A3    1    1     1
B1B2  10   12    11    
B3    100  200   300
```

EDIT: There are `n` columns in total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 ~ /^[AB]1$/ { for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) val[$1,i]=$i; next }
$1 ~ /^[AB]2$/ { p=$1; sub(2,1,p); $1=p $1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) $i=($i + val[p,i])/2 }
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -t
A1A2  3    3.5  1.5
A3    1    1    1
B1B2  10   12   11
B3    100  200  300
```

Comment: It seems that the output file is not tab-delimited how it was at the beginning. How can I be sure that the file is tab-delimited?

Comment: Add `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` to the top of the awk script and remove the `| column -t` after the call to awk. It's extremely important if/when your input/output files have a specific delimiter (e.g. a tab character) that you state that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/[AB][12]/{a=substr($1,1,1);
                  k=a"1"a"2";
                  c1[k]+=$2; c2[k]+=$3; c3[k]+=$4; n[k]++; next} 
               1; 
             END{for(k in c1) 
                     print k, c1[k]/n[k], c2[k]/n[k], c3[k]/n[k]}' file | sort | column -t

A1A2  3    3.5  1.5
A3    1    1    1
B1B2  10   12   11
B3    100  200  300
```

pattern match grouped rows, create a key, calculate sum of all fields and count of rows per key; print unmatched rows; when done print the averaged rows, since order is not preserved sort and pipe to `column` for easy formatting.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that there are n columns in the file.